# Check specific scanf format

Tags: c

I have this scanf code line:

```
scanf("%d,%d %d,%d", &X, &Y, &dirX, &dirY);
```

How can I check if the input, which should be for example `1,2 3,4` (2 commas) is indeed written like this, and only like this?

I don't want to accept `1,2,3,4` (3 commas) for example.

Comment: written like this and not like `1,1,1,1`? Its a little confusing. You want the user to enter `1,2,3,4` only and not any other numbers?

Comment: Note the space between the integers :) 1,1 1,1 is acceptable, while 1,1,1,1 is not.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the first 2 numbers to be separated by a comma, then a space, then 2 more numbers separated by a comma?

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of arguments successfully converted. So check that is `== 4`

Comment: You got that right Fabio!

Comment: What do you mean with "like this"?. Comma Separated? How about std::cin?

Comment: @Gerstrong this is a C question.

Comment: The question is unclear - it is clarified in the subsequent comments, but the clarification should be made by editing the question *in response* to comments, rather then adding more comments.

Comment: What should be done with input like `1,2 3,4 ,`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is check the return value of `scanf()` to see whether the user has entered the input is the proper format or not. Like

```
int main (void)
{
    int i, j, k, l;

    if(scanf("%d,%d %d,%d", &i, &j, &k, &l) != 4)
        printf("User entered input in wrong format\n");
        printf("please enter in the format i,j k,l");
        //exit here
    else
        printf("%d %d %d %d", i, j, k, l);
}
```

---

This uses the fact that if user enters input in some other format (other then 1,2 3,4) then `scanf()` will not be able to read all the `4` inputs, and thus will not return `4`.

Comment: I think you mean `if(scanf("%d,%d %d,%d", &i, &j, &k, &l) != 4)`, but good idea! I still do not understand what "like this" is meant to be though.

Comment: @Gerstrong, Ya, I noticed that.. Corrected. About what it is meant to be.. I am also not very sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need exact input checking, why not to use just `scanf("%s", &s)` (just string) and then `strncmp(3)`?

Formatted input is just about format, not semantics. So option is to put on `scanf` only general format validation like field width, field type (digits or alphanumeric), delimiters and so on. Semantics check goes onto different level.

If you need serious check of input like both format and semantics, I'd like to recommend tools like [flex](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bison) and [bison](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bison). They require more attention but they are MUCH more powerful.

Speaking in other words you definitely need something like:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int num. i, j, k, l;

    // Check format.
    num = scanf("%d,%d %d,%d", &i, &j, &k, &l);
    assert(num == 4);

    // Check semantics.
    assert((i == 1) && (j ==2) && (k == 3) && (l == 4));
}
```

Comment: A bit over my level. Thanks mate :)

Comment: He is not after exactly "1,2 3,4", but rather two comma separate pairs matching %d rather then four comma separated values.  i.e. there is no comma between the two pairs.  The question could do with some clarification - it is cleared up in the comments.

Comment: Yes, originally it was not so clear and then I understood this answer may be useful for future. Let us see if people will vote for it as useful. If not, will be deleted to keep SO clear place :-).